# PHP show_source not working on my server (Altervista)

Tags: php

I am trying to display the PHP source of a file inside a page. I am using show_source function in this way:

```
<?php
$nomefile = $_REQUEST['nome'];
show_source($nomefile);
?>
```

When I try this code on my local PC (using USBWebserver v8.6), it works smoothly, displaying the PHP code of the page. But when I try it on my remote webserver (Altervista), I only get an empty page.

I even try to substitute variable $nomefile with name "visite.php", which is the name of a file residing in the same folder, but still I get no result? I try with echo show_source(...), but no result again.

Is there an error in my code? Or maybe show_source is not compatible with all version of PHP? Is there any easy alternative?

Thanks a lot
Giancarlo Perlo - Italy

Comment: add your show_source() code too

Comment: Check if [`save_mode`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.sect.safe-mode.php#ini.safe-mode) is enabled on your remote webserver

Comment: [*This function is now also affected by safe_mode and open_basedir.*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-file.php) An alternative would be [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) with [`highlight_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-string.php). Be very careful allowing a user to specify the file to show contents of too; in fact, I would use a whitelist array of files to allow and check that it's *strictly* found in that list (no deviations).

Comment: (And that includes directory paths with filenames in the whitelist array.)

Comment: P.S
Thanks to Jarred Fish, this solution is working:

 <?php $nomefile = $_REQUEST['nome']; $contenuto =
> file_get_contents($nomefile, true); highlight_string($contenuto); ?>